# How can I open links in web browser with default browser in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, web, browser

I have a TCP/IP based windows form chat application. I've been using a web browser to display the communication because the HTML is easier than windows form drawitem. 
I have a regex, what recognize the links, and put them into an  tag. I'd like to open these links with the default browser. 
How can I do this? 
I found a code on this page, but it doesn't work. 
[this was the wrong solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927696/webbrowser-control-open-default-browser-on-click-on-link)

Answer (score 1):

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("https://www.google.com/");
```

Obviously your link is going to look different than that, but that code will change the url of the webBrowser.